# XCode plist editor inserts comma in values over 1000 creating problems

Tags: xcode, plist, nsnumber

I enter a value "43200" (12 hours in seconds) into a NSNumber field and save. XCode somehow changes the value to "43,200" - inserting a comma. However if I look at the xml file the value is saved as `<integer>43200</integer>`, so everything should be fine at this point.
However, the next time I click on the value, XCode cuts the comma and everything right of it. So the value ends up being 43. XCode probably autosaves at this point, even if I just press Escape and close the file, then when I look at the xml data the value is changed to `<real>43</real>` (!) What is going on, this must be a bug??
(XCode 4.6.2)

[image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/147970342/stackoverflow/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-29%20at%2017.06.28.png]

Comment: Where/what in XCode is this "NSNumber field" that you refer to?

Comment: Added a screenshot for you. It says Number under Type column. The value is at its right.

Comment: Oddly enough, I just tried the same thing and it never enters a comma.  However, if I DO put a comma in the number, it does strip it and everything to the right.  (I'm also running 4.6.2.)

Comment: This is still a problem in Xcode 6.1.1. Xcode no longer cuts off field values after the comma, but Xcode still changes `integer` to `real` in the XML when you re-edit a Number field in which Xcode auto-inserted a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem- any plist entry with a comma would drop all the digits to the right of the comma. Infruriating.

It IS a bug in Xcode 4.6.2.

The good news is, it got fixed in 5.0. Just upgrade and you'll be fine.